# make parameter default value a CONSTANT = a string in PHP

Tags: php

Im trying to create the default value of a function parameter, as the combination of a constant concatenated with a string, but it seems like I cant make concatenating operations in there.

```
public function __construct($test = __DIR__."/mypath") { ...
```

of course, I could make this>

```
public function __construct($test = null) {
    if($test === null) {
        $test = __DIR__."/mypath"
    }
```

BUt I was wondering if there was a cleaner way. Is there?

Answer (score 2):

Create a class variable, and then re-assign it construction

```
var $path = __DIR__."/mypath"; // Really better off to be an absolute path

public function __construct($test = null) {
    if($test !== null) {
        $this->path = $test;
}
```

Comment: Maybe make it private, too, depending on the application. If you're working with file paths I usually make getters that way it cant be changed after instantiation. But that could be way off the mark. E.g. private $path = ....

Comment: That is the same I explained in the second case. I wanted to do it cleaner, not longer =)

Comment: I'm not sure if you can get any cleaner than that. But this method has the benefit of actually being able to use that path variable in other places in the class, unless you're doing something else with the $test variable after the code you have posted.

Comment: The former is possible in 5.6